# BusinessObject on MSSQL: How can I change language at session level?

Tags: t-sql, business-objects

I have a MSSQL server set to use US dates (MM-DD-YY), but have reports defined for BusinessObjects that need to use British dates (DD-MM-YY).

The SQL which these reports runs will work if the T-SQL command **SET LANGUAGE 'British English'** is first used in the session.

Is there any way to get BusinessObjects to specify the language via T-SQL when it opens the session?

Changing the default language on the server is not an option as it is shared with other applications requiring US dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting this using the ConnectInit property on the connection? This assumes that you want this set for all reports that run against that BOBJ Universe.